# Is there any PL/SQL query for converting number to Arabic words?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to convert an amount value to Arabic words in oracle pl/sql. Can any one please help me here.

Comment: Does this SO question help? [Oracle: convert numbers to words in other language than English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167224/oracle-convert-numbers-to-words-in-other-language-than-english)

Comment: Try this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=spell-numbers-in-arabic